# How to access CompareEditor UI element in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, git, user-interface

I am trying to access the code inside of a diff view UI element in Eclipse. So for example when you right click on a file and select compare with...

This is straight forward with the regular java editor. Its IWorkbenchPartReference is an instance of IEditorReference and it contains a StyledText SWT element that allows me to access the code in the editor. But I can't figure out how to access the code in the diff view.

I know that the IWorkbenchPartReference for the diff view is still an instance of IEditorReference, to be specific the CompareEditor class, but what swt elements is it composed of beyond that?

Comment: This is a complex editor. Perhaps you should tell us what you are trying to do. Have you read the [Compare support](http://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fcompare.htm&cp=2_0_15) section of the help which covers this editor?

Comment: I have a plugin that tacks various user interactions with the ide. Currently I am trying to access code inside a compare editor when a developer mouses over or interacts with it. The only issue i'm facing is trying to figure out what components make up the editor so I know what IWorkbenchPartReference to listen for.